# Error correction : The chancellor was present on both occasions

Tags: exam-questions

> The chancellor was present on both occasions.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct ? I thought it to be error free but then to confirm myself I googled for the sentence  and found varying answers, somewhere its written to use *at both occasions* and somewhere I found to use *both the occasions*. I am pretty sure former correction is wrong but what about the later one ? Do we need to use article *the* here or its fine not to use it ?

Comment: "both the occasions" is probably just a contraction of "both of the occasions". Adding some examples of various usages you are asking about would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either:

> The chancellor was present **on** both occasions.
>   The chancellor was present **on** both *of the* occasions.

The difference of *at* vs. *on* has to do with the prepositions in general.
Here, *on* refers to the event, while *at* refers to the location.

> I will see you **on** the occasion of my birthday party. (the activity itself)
>   I will see you **at** the birthday party. (where the party will be)

As you can see, *on* is more likely used with occasions.